# python selenium click on button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, onclick, click

I am quite new to python selenium and I am trying to click on a button which has the following html structure:

```html
<div class="b_div">

    <div class="button c_button s_button" onclick="submitForm('mTF')">
        <input class="very_small" type="button"></input>
        <div class="s_image"></div>
        <span>
           Search
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="button c_button s_button" onclick="submitForm('rMTF')" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <input class="v_small" type="button"></input>
        <span>
              Reset
        </span>
   </div>

</div>
```

I would like to be able to click both the `Search` and `Reset` buttons above (obviously individually).

I have tried a couple of things, for example:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button .c_button .s_button').click()
```

or,

```
driver.find_element_by_name('s_image').click()
```

or,

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('s_image').click()
```

but, I seem to always end up with `NoSuchElementException`, for example:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"s_image"}' ;
```

I am wondering if I can somehow use the onclick attributes of the HTML to make selenium click?

Any thoughts which can point me in the right direction would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For python, use the

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

and

```
ActionChains(browser).click(element).perform()
```

Comment: What is `element`?

Comment: @rosefun `element` may refer to:
`<h1>My First Heading</h1>`,
`<p>My first paragraph.</p>`,
`<button>Submit</button>`,
or anything between the start tag and end tag

Answer (score 148):

Remove space between classes in css selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button .c_button .s_button').click()
#                                           ^         ^
```

=>

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button.c_button.s_button').click()
```

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested. I get the same `NoSuchElementException` error!

Comment: @AJW, Try `print(driver.page_source)`, and check the html actually contains the element.

Comment: Thanks. I did `print(driver.page_source)` and found that it was named different. Strange. It clicks now when I took the spaces away and renamed. On a follow up tho: as you can see even the reset button and the search button has the same `class`: how does one distinguish between the search and reset buttons while clicking in this case?

Comment: @AJW, How aobut using xpath: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="button c_button s_button"][contains(., "Search")]')`

Comment: Thanks for the tip falsetru: I will experiment with it - I get the idea. Accepted your answer! Thanks again!

Comment: Is it possible to use selenium in tty?

Comment: @MortezaLSC, If you mean it's possible in system where there's no GUI, it's possible. Use headless browsers. For example, PhantomJS.

Comment: Would you be so nice to have a look at the following question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435984/radio-button-does-not-get-clicked-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 44):

try this:

download firefox, add the plugin "firebug" and "firepath"; after install them go to your webpage, start firebug and find the xpath of the element, it unique in the page so you can't make any mistake.

See picture:
[image: instruction]

`browser.find_element_by_xpath('just copy and paste the Xpath').click()`

Comment: Thank you very much for such a awesome lifehack. It saved many hours

Comment: does this not work on a mac bc both firebug and fire path aren't showing up as add ons

Comment: Some time it's not a problem of OS but Firefox version, last Firefox version has some problem with FirePath, I'm using Firefox 55.0.3

Comment: You can find the element on Firefox using: Tools->Web Developer->Inspector; click on the button at the GUI, on the inspector part, right click with the mouse on the relevant code-> copy and choose: CSS Selector / CSS Path / Xpath ...

Comment: Saved me hours... thanks mate.. now you don't need firebug only xPath do the whole job to find the xPath plugin here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath_finder/

Answer (score 9):

open a website https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/compilation and click on button to download the file and even i want to close the pop up if it comes using python selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 

#For Mac - If you use windows change the chromedriver location
chrome_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/compilation")

# driver.get("https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/")
# tabName = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Investment Adviser Data")
# tabName.click()

time.sleep(3)

# report1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='compilation-container ng-scope layout-column flex']//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[2]//button[1]")

report1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@analytics-label='IAPD - SEC Investment Adviser Report (GZIP)']")

# print(report1)
report1.click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem using Phantomjs as browser, so I solved in the following way:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.button.c_button.s_button').click()
```

Essentially I have added the name of the DIV tag into the quote.

Answer (score 5):

The following debugging process helped me solve a similar issue.

```
with open("output_init.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(driver.page_source.encode('ascii','ignore'))


xpath1 = "the xpath of the link you want to click on"
destination_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath1)
destination_page_link.click()


with open("output_dest.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(driver.page_source.encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

You should then have two textfiles with the initial page you were on ('output_init.txt') and the page you were forwarded to after clicking the button ('output_dest.txt'). If they're the same, then yup, your code did not work. If they aren't, then your code worked, but you have another issue.
The issue for me seemed to be that the necessary javascript that transformed the content to produce my hook was not yet executed.

Your options as I see it:

1. Have the driver execute the javascript and then call your find
   element code. Look for more detailed answers on this on
   stackoverflow, as I didn't follow this approach.
2. Just find a comparable hook on the 'output_dest.txt' that will produce the same result, which is what I did.
3. Try waiting a bit before clicking anything:

> xpath2 = "your xpath that you are going to click on"
>
> WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5).until(lambda x:
>   x.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2))

The xpath approach isn't necessarily better, I just prefer it, you can also use your selector approach.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and with **Firefox**, I got button element with the following steps:

- right click button of interest and select "Inspect Accessibility Properties"
- this opens the inspector. Right click the highlighted line and click "Print to JSON"
- this opens a new tab. Look for `nodeCssSelector` and copy the value

This allowed me to accept cookies of the website Yahoo by using.

```
url = "https://yahoo.com"
driver = Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn:nth-child(5)").click()
```

I tested this further and it allowed me to accept individual cookies with ease. Simply repeat the mentioned steps from before to get the button names.

```
url = "https://yahoo.com"
driver = Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".firstPartyAds > div:nth-child(2) > label:nth-child(1)").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".preciseGeolocation > div:nth-child(2) > label:nth-child(1)").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn").click()
```

Another method is to

- right click button of interest and select "Inspect"
- right click the highlighted line and click "Copy -> CSS Selector" or whatever you need (there are multiple options, including XPath)

However, I think the second method may include whitespaces depending on what you copy, so you might need to manually remove (some of) them. The first method seems to be more foolproof, but I don't know if/how it works on other browsers than Firefox. The second method should work for all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

`e = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 's_image').click()`

sometime it does not work!
you can try:

`e = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 's_image') driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", e)`

Answer (score 1):

**Use This code To Click On Button**

```
# finding the button using ID
button = driver.find_element_by_id(ID)

# clicking on the button
button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python , you could do something like

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "my_button")

element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

the reason for this is when you use `webdriver.find_element` the given element will be focused on, and when a button is focused, pressing "Enter" key will trigger a click event on that button.