# How to bypass disclaimer while scraping a website

Tags: python, phantomjs, scrape

I was able to scrape the following website before using "driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()" for work reason. What I was scraping were the price and the date.

https://www.cash.ch/fonds/swisscanto-ast-avant-bvg-portfolio-45-p-19225268/swc/chf

This stopped working some days ago due to a disclaimer page which I have to agree at first.

https://www.cash.ch/fonds-investor-disclaimer?redirect=fonds/swisscanto-ast-avant-bvg-portfolio-45-p-19225268/swc/chf

Once agreed I visually saw the real content, however the driver seems not, print out is [], so it must be still with the url of the disclaimer.

Please see code below.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv
    import os

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

    #Swisscanto
    driver.get("https://www.cash.ch/fonds/swisscanto-ast-avant-bvg-       portfolio-45-p-19225268/swc/chf")
    s_swisscanto = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    nav_sc = s_swisscanto.find_all('span', {"data-field-entry": "value"})
    date_sc = s_swisscanto.find_all('span', {"data-field-entry": "datetime"})

    print(nav_sc)
    print(date_sc)
    print("Done Swisscanton")
```

Comment: Try to find out if the disclaimer sets any cookie and do this before scraping. And you should check if you comply with the disclaimer because it is there for a reason

Comment: Hi Marget, could you further explain how to examine if the disclaimer sets any cookie? Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at my code, really short, just added to the post.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (I think the button you want to click in zustimmen?)

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://www.cash.ch/fonds/swisscanto-ast-avant-bvg-portfolio-45-p-19225268/swc/chf"

accept_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('zustimmen')
accept_button.click()

content = driver.page_source
```

More details here
[python selenium click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button)

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much! The situation is weird though... After clicking on "zustimmen" once, the browser remembers this and never asked again. The browser shows the page with price and date, but the scrapped page is still the one with disclaimer. If scrapping price and date I got [] printed out... Meaning I still didn't get to the real page.... Do you know why? And how to fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, I kind of got stuck there. Could you be so kind to run this short code? Once agreed, the real website is shown. But my print out is null.

Comment: Please have a look at my code, really short, just added to the post.