# how to click on this button using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```html
<button id="upload-resume" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ng-binding" ng-show="canUpload()" ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false">Continue</button>
```

how to click on this button using selenium python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python selenium click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button)

Comment: `button = browser.find_element_by_id('upload-resume')`
`button.click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
upload_button = driver.find_element_by_id("upload-resume")
upload_button.click()
```

If you wanna use Xpath , then you can use this code:

```
 upload_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[text()='Continue']")  
 upload_button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks but its got an error unable to locate element

Comment: Could you search for the locators? is id static ? or it has multiple web element associate with it

Comment: [link](https://application.careerbuilder.com/apply/cb/JHP6F667WD678MSNKZ7?ipath=JRGY1&siteid=ns_in_g&cbax_login=true&vid=VX30D2EE003DCD11E8976B35DF542A21B12706LM&domain=www.careerbuilder.com#/application/resume_upload/picked)

Comment: Yeah ! Gimme some time!

Comment: Where is upload button ?

Comment: u have to login i think its static

Comment: After login where is the upload button . provide the navigation steps

Comment: after login click on any job and it gets apply now button after that u get upload button

Comment: and also the checkbox

Comment: Yes that's fine , but I'm not able to find upload button manually.

Comment: the button will look like "continue"

Comment: After login what do I have to do to get the continue button ?

Comment: click on any job and u get apply now button after that u get continue button

Comment: Yeah I've got it ! you can use ID , as it is static and if you are facing any issue then use Explicit wait before clicking on the continue button.

Comment: for check box use this code :  check_box = driver.find_element_by_id('coverLetterCheckBox')  check_box.click()

Comment: explicit wait means

Comment: how to paste text in that box

Comment: Use this code just before clicking on WebElement, WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "upload-resume"))

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing its getting error

Comment: You need to go through this link :  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html