# Selenium can't find element neither by xpath or class

Tags: python, selenium

Selenium doesn't find this element :

```
 <input type="text" id="fe_text" class="mailtext" value="ayq94156@bcaoo.com" xpath="1" style="">
```

I tried this :

```
mail = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='fe_text']")
```

And this :

```
mail = driver.find_element(By.ID,"fe_text")
```

But it still says that it is unable to find the element

Basicly I need to copy the mail from this https://10minutemail.net/

Comment: Show us a minimal example.

Comment: We should see the HTML to see why does your script fail.

Comment: Might be your element is in the `iframe`. If yes then change to that particular item and then search for the target element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51515221/selenium-cant-locate-element This might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that my connexion was just to bad.I need to wait for the element to show up

```
try:
    mail = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fe_text")))
except:
    driver.quit()
```

Credit: Noob

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no iframe there so your locator should be identified straight away.
Try to add an explicit wait to handle this problem.