# python selenium click on page button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie about python selenium and I am trying to click on a button which has the following html structure:

```
 <a href="javascript:doPage('2');">2</a>
    -->
    <a href="#doPage2" onclick="javascript:doPage('2');">2</a>
    <img src="/images/common/divisionLine.gif" alt="" />
    <!--
    <a href="javascript:doPage('3');">3</a>
    -->
    <a href="#doPage3" onclick="javascript:doPage('3');">3</a>
    <img src="/images/common/divisionLine.gif" alt="" />
```

I want to click hyperlink name "2" or "3" like below code. But it does not work.

```
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@onclick=\"javascript:doPage('2');\"]"))).click()
```

When I run my python code, I got below error comment.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (577, 821)
```

Any thoughts which can point me in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share page URL?

Comment: have a look here, it could be useful for u ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button/37279279#37279279

Comment: page URL is like this (http://www.car.go.kr/jsp/report/fauRepInquiry_view.jsp) but this website is written by korean language.

Comment: The locator you  provided in your code isn't being found on the URL you provided. Please update your question with an example we can follow and an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to Replace click event with action class,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element("Your Element").click().perform()
```

If there is something which need to first hover, You can achieve with same class,

```
action.move_to_element("Your Element").build().perform()
```

Comment: I don't think, that this will help. The problem is, that some element hovers element OP wants to click. So firstly he has to deal with the hovering element, and then click

Comment: If so, Adding solution to Hover element.