# Xpath to select button from table cell depending on text contained within specific cell

Tags: selenium, xpath

On my web application I am attempting to select a button within a cell in a table.

Not every cell will contain a show details button and the button is only displayed depending on the text within that cell

Screenshot below

[image]

```
<td>
    Allocated
    <button ng-show="row.entitlementId" id="btnShowDetails" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width: 110px; float:right;" ng-click="showAllocationMonetaryDetails(row.entitlementId, CisBusinessID);" title="Show Details">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Show Details
    </button>
    <br>
    <div style="font-size: small; color: darkgreen" ng-show="row.manualEstablishCommandType >= 0">
         Adjustment
    </div>
    <div style="font-size: small; color: darkgreen" ng-show="row.manualReclaimCommandType >= 0">

    </div>
</td>
```

I attempted to use the following xpath to locate the show details button but it does not work.

```
("//td[contains(.,'Allocated') and (contains(@id,'btnShowDetails'))]")
```

Does anybody know how I can select the Show Details button?

Thanks

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button/37279279#37279279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@id='btnShowDetails'` is not an attribute of `td`, but attribute of child `button`

Try below XPath to select required element:

```
//td[starts-with(normalize-space(),'Allocated') and button[@id='btnShowDetails']]
```

or

```
//td[normalize-space(text())='Allocated' and button[@id='btnShowDetails']]
```

Comment: Thank you :) That has enabled me to select the cell which contains the button but whenever I use this xpath it does not isolate and select the button

Comment: If you want to select the button: `//td[normalize-space(text())='Allocated']/button[@id='btnShowDetails']`

Answer (score 2):

In your cell td there is no id attribute its under the button you can modify your xpath like this:

```
//td[contains(.,'Allocated') and (contains(button/@id,'btnShowDetails'))]
```