# How do I make Selenium click on this button?

Tags: python, selenium

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="Buttons--stackOnMobile">
    <li class="col">
        <button class="Button">Sign In</button>
    </li>
    <li class="col col--secondary">
        <a class="Button Button--alt" href="/account/create">Create an Account</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col hide">
        <button class="Button">Sign In</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to make selenium click on Sign in button.

I'm coding in Python 3.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python selenium click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button)

Comment: You need to post your python code. You have posted HTML so far. Also include the full error message that you get when running your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two buttons are present with the same xpath.

**if you want to click first button then use below code**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
button= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//button[@class="Button"])[1]')))
button.click()
```

**if you want to click the second button then use below code**

```
  wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    button= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//button[@class="Button"])[2]')))
    button.click()
```