# I want to click! How can I do it using selenium, python and mozilla?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to click! How can I do it using selenium, python and mozilla?

[image: this is a screenshot of the code.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python selenium click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answer.