# How to click a button in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python script to open a web page, then a tab and then i want to click on a button. I am stuck on the last part. I am unable to click the find button. Here is the HTML code when i am using inspect in chrome.

[image: Code Snippet]

```
input value="Find" class="cuesButton" name="findButton" 
onclick="javascript:onFindSubmit()" type="button"
```

Here is the button i am trying to click:

[image: button to click]

I tried driver.find_element_by_name, element_by_id. It says method css selector doesnt have this element by name but it still fails.

Comment: sample code: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSubmit"]').click() `
inspect the element and get the xpath first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python selenium click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button)

Comment: Getting this error:selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="findButton"]"}

Answer (score 0):

2 things can be happening, 1 the page isn’t finished loading, to wait use WebDriverWait like so:

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

Or 2, the element is in an iframe , in this case you would need to switch to it like so:

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

You can switch using xpath, name, cssselector, and tag name

Comment: Tried both but still its not working. Here is the error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"Find"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)

Comment: Did you replace the respected values, like tag_name(“iframe”)

Comment: yes.. i used both Find, findButton..both didnt work