# OSError: [WinError 6] Wrong descriptor error using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, subprocess, eoserror

Can you help me with my code? I want to parse phone numbers, but I need to activate button with tap. But this button is with a tag  and this is a problem for me. How can I fix it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
#from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchActions
#import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions


#TouchActions.tap
def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    remote = driver.get("https://www.olx.ua/uk/obyavlenie/68200jk71a-torpedo-pod-airbag-infiniti-g-07-14-infiniti-IDGRpUS.html#d97e6d976d;promoted")
    bt_elem = driver.find_elements_by_id("postNewAdLink")
    #print(bt_elem[0])
    #driver.find_elements_by_class_name("contact-button").click()
    #ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(bt_elem).perform().click()

    #bt_elem.get(0).click()
    #TouchActions.tap(bt_elem)

main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\radus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 945, in __del__
    self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\radus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1344, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] Wrong descriptor
```

Comment: Take a look here [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
  File "C:\Users\radus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 945, in __del__
    self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\radus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1344, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] Wrong descriptor
```

...implies that there an error with the `subprocess.Popen()` command.

---

As per the discussion in [Selenium 3.5.0-GeckoDriver 0.18.0-Python 3.6.1 : "OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid" is observed while close() is called through Python PyDev (Eclipse) unittest module](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4505) this issue was observed even while invoking `self.driver.close()` through *Python's* [unittest](/questions/tagged/unittest) module.

```
This is because there is no stdin defined in the `service.py` file for the `subprocess.Popen()` command. Underwater the subprocess tries to create a handle which also looks for stdin under Windows this gets a bit tricky when using `Bash` or `cx_Freeze`. So, `stdin` was defined as well, and the crash is gone. Optionally you can also use:

FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r')
subprocess.Popen(.... ,stdin=FNULL)
```

---

### Solution

The solution was merged from the [Also define stdin or it will crash on Python + cx_Freeze: WindowsErro…](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/4503) pull request and was available in `Selenium v3.8.1`

Ideally, you need toensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v80.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 80.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v80.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### tl; dr

[subprocess.Popen._cleanup() "The handle is invalid" error when some old process is gone](https://bugs.python.org/issue37380)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine... Your environment looks suspect.  If I were to hazard a guess (since it's the subprocess module complaining), maybe Selenium can't find chrome.exe in your PATH.  Does Chrome open before this exception?