# Parsing ASPX pages in Python

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, python-requests

I try to send a POST request, but in response I get the page itself with the parameters I enter, without clicking the "Search" button
How to "click" the "Search" button?

```
import requests

url = 'http://test-bankrot.interfax.ru/DebtorsSearch.aspx'

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'cookie': '_ym_uid=1594586199406955023; _ym_d=1594586199; ASP.NET_SessionId=luddoegxqnluqjdnpdd1vntq; bankrotcookie=c8e843d30d6ccd6079ea7b96c2e7f478; _ym_visorc_45311283=w; _ym_isad=2; debtorsearch=typeofsearch=Persons&orgname=&orgaddress=&orgregionid=&orgogrn=&orginn=&orgokpo=&OrgCategory=&prslastname=&prsfirstname=&prsmiddlename=&prsaddress=&prsregionid=&prsinn=&prsogrn=&prssnils=&PrsCategory=22&pagenumber=0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
}

data = {
'__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$DebtorSearch1$inputDebtor',
'__VIEWSTATE': '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',
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '6F6AFF56',
'__PREVIOUSPAGE': 'G5TC6z50AdtkCE0nCpNroKsLTuna4qHqwaa28PIWuQDz-GlERiDLkfEXck3wVAs7pF8fZ8djrQG9eeMgXOFDCkneZr6R7prLOOSyasD_P6NUwk7p0',
'ctl00$cphBody$rblDebtorType': 'Persons',
'ctl00$cphBody$ucPrsCategoryList$ddlBoundList': '22',
'ctl00$cphBody$PersonCode1$CodeTextBox': '234432432324',
'ctl00$DebtorSearch1$inputDebtor': 'поиск'
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(r.text)
```

I expect to receive a response

```
<table class="bank" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_cphBody_gvDebtors" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width:5%;">Категория</th><th scope="col">Должник</th><th scope="col">ИНН</th><th scope="col">ОГРНИП</th><th scope="col" style="width:7%;">СНИЛС</th><th scope="col">Регион</th><th scope="col">Адрес</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td style="width:22%;">
                            Физическое лицо
                        </td><td style="width:20%;">
                            <a href="/PrivatePersonCard.aspx?ID=1A1156A46B4F20586214F9F74E65C96D" title="Карточка должника ed d312d w">
                                ed d312d w
                            </a>
                        </td><td style="width:6%;">
                            234432432324
                        </td><td style="width:6%;">
                            
                        </td><td>324-324-324 34</td><td style="width:15%;">
                            г. Севастополь
                        </td><td style="width:25%;">
                            dfdfs
                        </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can't seem to access the URL you've provided, getting 404. Generally speaking if you're need browser activity, it's more likely you'll need to use selenium for this job. Unless you can re-engineer the HTTP requests to get data, which I can't tell at present with the URLS you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can click buttons with requests, so you will have to use selenium.
Here is another article explaining how to click
a button: [python selenium click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button)