# Cannot click on an xpath selected object Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click to an object that I select with Xpath, but there seems to be problem that I could not located the element. I am trying to click accept on the page's "Terms of Use" button. The code I have written is as

```
    driver.get(link)
    
    accept_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="terms-ok"]')
    accept_button.click()
    
    prov = driver.find_element_by_id("province-region")
    prov.click()
```

Here is the HTML code I have:

[image]

And I am getting a "NoSuchElementException". My goal is to click this "Kabul Ediyorum" button at the bottom of the HTML code. I started to think that we have some restrictions on the tasks we could do on that page. Any ideas ?

Comment: Try getting the page source (via your Selenium driver) and inspect it; maybe the website detects you're using a bot and modify your experience

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button

Comment: Could you share the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what the issue might be.
But you could try the following:

> 1. Try to locate the element by its visible text

```
accept_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Kabul Ediyorum']").click()
```

> 2. Try with `ActionChains`

> For that you need to import `ActionChains`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

accept_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Kabul Ediyorum']")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(on_element=accept_button).perform()
```

> Also make sure you have `implicitly wait`

```
# implicitly wait
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

> Or `explicit wait`

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Kabul Ediyorum']"))).click()
```

Hope this helped!