# Selenium unable to locate and click a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to make my script click the checkout button with WebDriverWait, XPath, Class, but it doesn't work anyways :

HTML

```
<div class="confirm-container row">
    :before
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">
            <span>Effettua l'ordine</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    ::after
</div>
```

> 1st try

```
var = '//*[@id="purchase-app"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/button'
WebDriverWait(web, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, var)))
web.find_element_by_xpath(var).click()
```

> 2nd try
> `web.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-primary').click()`

> 3rd try
> `ActionChains(web).click(web.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-primary')).perform()`

Comment: I have'nt made a research about it, but when I tried to make selenium press something like a subscribe button in Youtube it didn't work, I figured Google might be making it harder to do automatially. Not sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `Explicit wait`, try to have a **relative xpath** :

`1st try` issue can be resolved by the below code :

```
WebDriverWait(web, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Effettua l'ordine']/.."))).click()
```

`2nd try` `web.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-primary').click()` - **class name does not accept spaces** so, use `css selector` instead :

```
web.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-primary').click()
```

same issue with **3rd try**.

**Update 1 :**

The issue is that, the button you are looking is in **iframe** so you need to switch over it before interaction :

**Code  :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src^='/store/purchase?namespace']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I adjusted them as you said but it still doesn't work

Comment: What is the error ? and which code are you using ?

Comment: For the first code i received this `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.btn.btn-primary"}`
and for the second one this `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`

Comment: Can you share page URL ?

Comment: this is the one `Accedi con Xbox Live` ?

Comment: `WebDriverWait(web, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.MuiListItemIcon-root div[aria-label='Xbox Live']"))).click()` - try this

Comment: oh really :(.. I thought in a different way

Comment: If you want I can send you a video of the site where I show the button I want and html

Comment: html screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/pNzGHST
video: https://streamable.com/xogisq

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
ActionChains(browser).click(element).perform()
```

while element refer to anything between the start tag and end tag.

as stated in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61036237/11884764