# How to use Python Selenium to click a button?

Tags: python, selenium

I have tried several ways to make a button clickable using Selenium in Python and it seems none of my tries were good enough.

This is how the HTML looks like:

```
< class="divModulesItems" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-bottom:0px;" onclick="location.href='CSIQTHourEntry.aspx'"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-370 248.3 100 100" style="enable-background:new -370 248.3 100 100;" xml:space="preserve" focusable="false">

<br Enter <br hours
```

This is the latest I tried, by using onclick method:

```
EnterHours = HoursEntryPortal.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[ contains(text(), 'hours')]"));
```

Also, by using the above code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any idea how could I make this button clickable? Maybe my sintax is not correct or I omit something.

Comment: I don't see `Manager_wp1078203230_wp724786216_linkContainer` in the provided HTML

Comment: What is `ONCLICK` ? Does your framework use it's own customized locator?

Comment: I just realized I've put a test variant here.
This is what I wanted to say:

```
EnterHoursElement = HoursEntryPortal.find_element(By.XPATH(//*[@id="Manager_wp1078203230_wp724786216_LinkWidgetSpanTitle"]))
```

Also tried this way:

`
#EnterHours = HoursEntryPortal.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[ contains(text(), 'hours')]"));

#EnterHours = HoursEntryPortal.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[ IsDisplayed() = ‘hours’ ]"));

Using the text() method I get the following error:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Instead of the handcrafted HTML, update the question with the text based actual HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python selenium click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button)